# Output the Collatz Tree using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am implementing the Collatz tree in VBA as discussed at:
[Collatz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/233508/rows-of-the-collatz-tree?newreg=4f1b734450b84e9f8c80836229858254)

Using the logic as discussed at: http://oeis.org/search?q=+A088976&sort=&language=&go=Search

Given an Excel file with a Sheet named OUTPUT, my code which missing few CHILD values is:

```
Public Sub CollatzTree()
' Collatz tree built as per the pseudocode:
' — The root node is 1.
' — For a given node n:
' ·If n is odd, its only child is 2×n.
' ·If n is even, one of its children is 2×n. If (n-1)/3 is an integer and not already part of the tree, its right child is (n-1)/3.
' — Recursively and infinitely define the tree this way, beginning from the root node.

' — We can read this tree as rows, from left to right, to create a list of lists: [1], [2], [4], [8], [16], [32, 5], [64, 10], [128, 21, 20, 3], [256, 42, 40, 6], [512, 85, 84, 80, 13, 12], [1024, 170, 168, 160, 26, 24], [2048, 341, 340, 336, 320, 53, 52, 48], ...

    GoTo x1

x1:
    Dim m&, n&, i&, j&, k

    j = 1&

    ReDim k(1& To j)

    Sheets("Output").Select
    Sheets("Output").Cells(1, 1) = "1"

    m = 1&
    n = 1&
    For i = 1& To 12&
        m = m + 1&
        n = n + 1&
        If Sheets("Output").Cells(m - 1&, n - 1&) > 4& And Sheets("Output").Cells(m - 1&, n - 1&) Mod 6& = 4& Then
            Sheets("Output").Cells(m + 1&, n) = 2& * Sheets("Output").Cells(m - 1&, n - 1&)
            k(j) = 2& * Sheets("Output").Cells(m - 1&, n - 1&)
            j = j + 1&
            ReDim Preserve k(1& To j)
            Sheets("Output").Cells(m, n) = (Sheets("Output").Cells(m - 1&, n - 1&) - 1&) \ 3&
            k(j) = (Sheets("Output").Cells(m - 1&, n - 1&) - 1&) \ 3&
            j = j + 1
            ReDim Preserve k(1& To j)
        Else
            Sheets("Output").Cells(m, n) = 2& * Sheets("Output").Cells(m - 1&, n - 1&)
            k(j) = 2& * Sheets("Output").Cells(m - 1&, n - 1&)
            j = j + 1&
            ReDim Preserve k(1& To j)
        End If
    Next i

' GoTo x2

    m = 2&
    n = 1&
    For i = 1& To 12&
        m = m + 1&
        n = n + 1&
        If Sheets("Output").Cells(m - 1&, n - 1&) = "" Or Sheets("Output").Cells(m - 1&, n - 1&) = "0" Then
        Else
            If Sheets("Output").Cells(m - 1&, n - 1&) > 4& And Sheets("Output").Cells(m - 1&, n - 1&) Mod 6& = 4& Then
y1:
                If Sheets("Output").Cells(m + 1&, n) = "" Then
                    Sheets("Output").Cells(m + 1&, n) = 2& * Sheets("Output").Cells(m - 1&, n - 1&)
                    k(j) = 2& * Sheets("Output").Cells(m - 1&, n - 1&)
                    j = j + 1&
                    ReDim Preserve k(1& To j)
y2:
                    Sheets("Output").Cells(m, n) = (Sheets("Output").Cells(m - 1&, n - 1&) - 1&) \ 3&
                    k(j) = (Sheets("Output").Cells(m - 1&, n - 1&) - 1&) \ 3&
                    j = j + 1
                    ReDim Preserve k(1& To j)
                Else
                    m = m + 1&
                    GoTo y1
                End If
            Else
y3:
                If Sheets("Output").Cells(m, n) = "" Then
                    Sheets("Output").Cells(m, n) = 2& * Sheets("Output").Cells(m - 1&, n - 1&)
                    k(j) = 2& * Sheets("Output").Cells(m - 1&, n - 1&)
                    j = j + 1&
                    ReDim Preserve k(1& To j)
                Else
                    m = m + 1&
                    GoTo y3
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    m = 0
    n = 0

x2:
    For i = 1 To UBound(k)
        Debug.Print k(i);
    Next i

End Sub
```

How to get all the values that are getting missed. That is, if we run code with Goto x2 enabled, it outputs 5,32 and 3,20 pairs. But if Goto x2 is disabled, the 5,32 pair is there but 30 of 3,20 pair is overwritten.

Comment: Why use `GoTo` and things like `m&,` at all? VBA is more modern than old-school BASIC. The code you have is harder to read than need be.